# document.activeElement is null in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

I have an eventlistener for onmousedown. The functions removes elements from DOM. If I click into an inputfield the currently focused element is removed from DOM.
--> document.activeElement becomes null in Internet Explorer and inputfield is not focused

It can be reproduced with this snippet. Focus the A-tag with "Tab" and click into inputfield afterwards.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body onmousedown="test(event);">
  <a href="#">Test</a>
  <input type="text"/>
  <script>
    function test(evt) {
      var elem = document.body.querySelector("A");
      elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas why this happens and how I can avoid it?

Comment: Returning true or false doesn't change anything

Comment: ok, blind shot, missed. Does it also occurs when you attach the event using `document.body.addEventListener('mousedown', test)` ?

Comment: yes it does, no difference